# How to read comma separated values within one cell of an excel file via formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

assume in an excel file, cell `a1` contains (comma separated values) `100, 250, 3`. Then how can one write a formula for cells `a2`, `a3`, and `a4` such that cell `a2` becomes `100`, `a3` becomes `250`, and `a4` becomes `3`.

Comment: The linked duplicate is about how to split data on a specific delimiter. There are several good answers that you can draw ideas from. Personally I like to use [`FILTERXML()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) which is also included in the linked dupe. Just transpose the data. Just know that another viable option would be to use PowerQuery which allows to split data into rows too.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

I'm pretty sure there is an easier way to do this, specially if you got E365, but you can make a work around to handle it.

Formula in column B is: `=VALUE(LEFT(A1;SEARCH(",";A1)-1))`

Column C: `=VALUE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1;B1&", ";"");SEARCH(",";SUBSTITUTE(A1;B1&", ";""))-1))`

Column D: `=VALOR(SUBSTITUTE(A1;B1&", "&C1&", ";""))`

Notice this will work only if your data is always like the pattern you posted:

INTEGER, INTEGER, INTEGER

If the pattern changes, the formula won't work!

Another aproach woould be using an UDF in VBA:

```
Public Function RETURN_INDEX(ByVal vRng As Range, ByVal vIndex As Integer) As Integer
RETURN_INDEX = Split(vRng.Text, ", ")(vIndex - 1)
End Function
```

This UDF will ask for the rng containing your data and what index you want (first one, second one, and so no)

So, to get 250 (second one) you would do: `=RETURN_INDEX(A1;2)`

Comment: +, but reminder that OP is looking to have data into rows.

Comment: @JvdV I totally forgot about that! My bad